# Can partial key be duplicated

Tags: primary-key

When deciding a  weak entity's primary key,we use the related strong entity's primarykey + partial key of the weak entity, I want to know if the partial key can be duplicated or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition a key is supposed to be irreducible. That means no proper subset of a key is required to be unique. So the answer is yes, the attributes of any part of a key can have duplicate values provided the key as a whole remains unique.

Answer (score 1):

Partial keys can't be duplicated since it's used to uniquely identify some record with the help of weak key. Below is a very useful link:
[Partial key architecture](http://ion.uwinnipeg.ca/~rmcfadye/2914/hypergraph/partial.html)

Comment: suppose the strong entity is employee and the dependent is the weak entity, if the partial key is dependent's name obviously there can be more than one person with the same name so why can't the partial key be duplicated?